# MLE for lower bound of Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution, stationary-processes

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, . . . , $X_n$ be a random sample from a $Uniform(θ, 1)$ population, where $θ < 1$.

(a) Find the MLE $\widehat{\theta}$ of $θ$.

(b) Find constants c and d (possibly depending on n) such that, c+d$\widehat{\theta}$ is unbiased for $θ$.

The likelihood of $θ$ being greater than $X_1$ is zero, but what is the likelihood of it being lower $X_1$. Is it the $θ^{-n}$ (same as when we try to estimate the higher limit of the Uniform Distribution.

I understand that $θ$ should be the minimum of the sample and 1 should be the max of the sample (ideally), but how to derive it mathematically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Likelihood Function for the Uniform Density $(\theta, \theta+1)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722101/likelihood-function-for-the-uniform-density-theta-theta1)

Comment: @fgp If Unif(theta,1) is what I believe it is, this question is not a duplicate of 722101.

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood of a sample $\mathbf x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ in $(0,1)$ is
$$
L(\theta\mid\mathbf x)=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\mathbf 1_{[\theta,1]}(x_k)}{1-\theta}=\frac{\mathbf 1_{\theta\leqslant\min\mathbf x}}{(1-\theta)^n}.
$$
Surely you can deduce which value $\hat\theta(\mathbf x)$ of $\theta$ maximizes this.